# Is there a password manager for Ubuntu

Tags: password

What is the most popular open source password manager which I can use on a Ubuntu machine or preferably across Ubuntu/Windows machines with some form of data compatibility. If there is a free web based version, that would be even more preferable.

Answer (score 13):

Yes there is [keepass](http://www.keepassx.org/) and several others (list below). To install **keepass** type in terminal

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

## OR

To install from software center, [keepass2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/keepass2/) and [keepassX](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/keepassx/), you can just click button below

### For keepass2

[image: Download from software center]

### For keepassX

[image: Download from software center]
[image: screen shot keepass2]
[image: screen shot keepassX]
Source:

- [How to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/93798/install-keepass-password-safe-on-your-ubuntu-or-debian-based-linux-system/%5C)
- [Keepass](http://www.keepassx.org/)
- [Tech radar](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/8-of-the-best-linux-password-managers-916152)

## AND

There are several others...

- [Fiagaro's Password Manager](http://fpm.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gpass](http://projects.netlab.jp/gpass/)
- [Gpassword Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpasswordman/)
- [Gringotts](http://gringotts.shlomifish.org/)
- [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/)
- [MyPasswords](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mypasswords7/)
- [PasswordSafe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/)
- [Revelation](http://freecode.com/projects/revelation)

Comment: +1 for KeePassX, it has worked flawlessly for me. Haven't used on Windows, but it has a windows target on the download page.

Comment: I am agree, KeePass has cool organazing features, and it encrypts file with password.

Comment: @Takkat yes there are, just watch answer I have edited it. :)

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu/Gnome has *gnome-keyring* as secure password safe.
(KDE provides with kwallet an an similar service.)

This approaches works for all applications compatible to the gnome (or kde) environment.

You can also find applications like *subversion*, which are capable to work with both services.

So normally you have all needed functionality already on board.
The problem is if you use some "foreign" software like firefox or chromium.

For some of them you can find some workarounds or configuration tweaks:

- firefox: https://github.com/infinity0/mozilla-gnome-keyring
- chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxPasswordStorage

For displaying/export all your passwords in your keyring you can use
the following script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import pygtk
    pygtk.require('2.0')
    import gtk # sets app name
    import gnomekeyring

    def hack():
        for keyring in gnomekeyring.list_keyring_names_sync():
            for id in gnomekeyring.list_item_ids_sync(keyring):
                item = gnomekeyring.item_get_info_sync(keyring, id)
                print '[%s] %s = %s' % (
                        keyring, item.get_display_name(), item.get_secret())
            else:
                if len(gnomekeyring.list_item_ids_sync(keyring)) == 0:
                    print '[%s] --empty--' % keyring

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        hack()
```

credits: This script is from [Michael Schurter](http://blog.schmichael.com/2008/10/30/listing-all-passwords-stored-in-gnome-keyring/)

For other applications my advice is to use an gpg encrypted textfile as your "brain-extension".

This can easily shared between different computers.
If you want to synchronize the content, use a directory with one file per password to avoid synchronization collisions.